# How to create a customer attribute only for one store?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, customer-attribute, scope

I can create a customer attribute using below script:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomerMobileNumber\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_no', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Mobile Number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'unique' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);


        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'mobile_no')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Please note this attribute is marked as required. I want to show this attribute only on store2 registration page.

Is it possible to create this attribute only for store2 ?

Comment: you can assign a customer attribute to a website but not to a store. If you have more stores in one website I guess there is no easy way to handle that. For adding an attribute to a specific website you can just use `$attribute->setWebsite($website)->save()` but most likely you know that :-)